# git - do not push local changes, but receive remote changes in new branch

Tags: git, gitignore

This may already have an answer; I'm just not sure how to search for it.

Here's my situation: I have a repo that has a configuration file in it called `environments.json`. There are changes I need to make to this file when working locally that I don't want to commit or get pushed back to the origin. OK, fine; that's what `git ignore` is for.

But when I set that up, it also means that when I pull a new branch from origin, I don't get any updates made by others to that file. On a daily basis, that isn't an issue, but every so often a new environment object may be added to the file (a new AWS instance, for example), and I do need to get that info.

So my question is: how can I set up git so that when I commit and push my repo, it does not include any changes I've made to `environments.json`, but when I do a pull, or get a new branch, I do receive changes to the file that others have made and pushed to origin (even if they overwrite my local changes)?

Comment: You should probably be using a separate file `local.json` that is an untracked copy of `environment.json`, with perhaps a script that can generate `local.json` on demand from whatever `environment.json` you have checked out.

Comment: can't you use [`dotenv.js`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the name of the file in `.git/info/exclude`

This file does not get committed back to the remote repo and will prevent changes to noted files from being staged.

I imagine from time to time this will result in conflicts but they should be easy enough to manage.

https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/#explicit-repository-excludes

Comment: Thank you, that sounds like what I need.